# Android. ImageView won't position itself correctly

Tags: android, imageview

I'm trying to place an image that fills the width of the screen, has the height of the actual image (wrap_content) and sits at the very bottom of the Layout.

I've wrote the below code, but between the second ImageView (the one with drawable/user_board) and the very bottom of the screen, there is a small space. Why is this? I've tried setting padding and margins to 0dp, but it seems it doesn't do the trick. Any ideas?

Here is the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:id="@+id/LayoutBoard"
                android:noHistory="true"
                android:padding="0dp" >
    <ImageView
        android:src="@drawable/game_interface_background"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:scaleType="matrix" />
    <ImageView
        android:src="@drawable/user_board"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:padding="0dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Have you used hierarchyviewer to see what the actual padding and margin values look like at runtime?

Comment: hmm. No. I haven't used it before, but i'll google it. Thanks.

Comment: It's very useful for these sort of things. Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doesn't your `user_board` image have some transparent space at the bottom? Or maybe you can try setting negative value in the padding field of the second `ImageView`.

Comment: Omg! That's what it was ! I knew it was something simple that i just missed. :D I do so love this website :D

Answer (score 1):

Use `android:scaleType="fitXY"` and the bitmap contained in your `ImageView` will be resized to fit the whole `ImageView`. So using this attribute in both your imageViews will probably hide that empty space. However keep in mind that this does not keep the aspect ratio of the image. See [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html) for more information about the `android:scaleType` attribute tag and the possible values it can take.

Comment: Nope. Doesn't seem to work. The hell is going on here :)) Now i'm angry ! I must be missing something, but i can't figure out what

Comment: @AndreiBogdan I just tried your xml code and seems to work (with different images of course). Maybe is happening what Dmytro Titov says.